# Flask/Gunicorn with 4 workers: Does long polling block a worker?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I wrote something like this (with more code, the important part is the `sleep(5)`):

```
def get(self):
    import time
    time.sleep(5)
    return jsonify({'result':'OK'})
```

I start my server like this:

```
gunicorn serve:app -b 127.0.0.2:8000 -w 4
```

While the app is "sleeping" is that blocking a whole worker? How does this affect `gunicorn`'s ability to respond?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`gunicorn` will default to using synchronous workers, which will only serve one request at a time, so yes will consume that worker for the lifetime of the long poll. `gunicorn` does support [asynchronous workers](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/design.html#async-workers), which will allow a worker to serve other requests along side the long poll - see [choosing a worker type](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/design.html#choosing-a-worker-type):

```
gunicorn -k gevent -b 127.0.0.1:8000 serve:app
```

Comment: Can I still use `-w 4` with that?

Comment: Yes, and there's advice on that page as to what to set that to. Also related is [`--worker-connections`](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#worker-connections)

Comment: For the record, gunicorn automatically monkey-patches when async worker is used. Otherwise, you would have to manually monkey-patch or use `gevent.sleep(5)`.

Comment: @DazWorral, Do you have to change anything in your application to switch to asynchronous?  What's actually happening under the hood that would now make it non blocking?